# Перемещение контента с помощью js

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

делаю перемещение контента под ссылку, на которую кликнет пользователь. Все вроде работает, но когда открываю контент первый раз - все нормально, второй раз через другую ссылку - контент открывается и быстро закрывается. И потом чередуется, то нормально открывается, то плохо. Что я делаю не так? Помогите пожалуйста.

```js
$(function() {
  /* Start DocumentReady */

  /* StartClickFunction */
  $('div.hideWrap a.hideBtn').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().append($('div.hideWrap>div.hideCont'));
    $(this).toggleClass('show').siblings('div.hideCont').slideToggle('normal');
    var hideBtn = $('div.hideWrap a.hideBtn').index($(this)),
      isShow = $(this).attr('class');
    //setCookie('hideBtn' + hideBtn, isShow, 365);
    return false;
  });
  /* End DocumentReady */
});
```

```css
.hideWrap {
  text-align: left;
  clear: both;
}

.hideBtn {
  display: block;
  background: transparent url('http://likbezz.ru/_example/_img/_lib1/_plus.gif') no-repeat left center;
  font: bold 11px/15px Verdana, sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  padding: 1px 14px 2px;
}

.hideBtn.show {
  background-image: url('http://likbezz.ru/_example/_img/_lib1/_minus.gif');
}

.hideCont {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js?ver=1.7.2"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://likbezz.ru/_fr/3/1844975.js"></script>

<div id="exContent" style="text-align:left;padding-top:50px;">
  <div class="hideWrap">
    <a class="hideBtn" href="javascript://" title="Показать\Скрыть блок">Показать</a>
    <div class="hideCont">Здесь располагается содержимое class "hideCont"</div>
  </div>
  <br />
  <br />
  <div class="hideWrap">
    <a class="hideBtn" href="javascript://" title="Показать\Скрыть блок">Показать</a>
  </div>
  <br />
  <br />
  <div class="hideWrap">
    <a class="hideBtn" href="javascript://" title="Показать\Скрыть блок">Показать</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Прикольный код, мне понравился)))) Проблема в том, что у тебя класс используется везде один и тот же, а точнее его состояние... соответственно если ты открыл 1 блок и не закрыв его открываешь следующий, то он не откроется, а закроется сначала. Я предлагаю при клике на новую ссылку, удалять все до этого сгенерированные классы, чтобы все блоки кроме нужного закрылись.

Comment: Да, с id всё будет чётко. Но обычно так не делается, так как это громоздкий код в котором можно запутаться если он не прокомментирован или проект повышенной сложности.

Comment: Вот нашёл небольшой пример
$("button").click(function () {
      $("p").toggle("slow");
    });  
Возможно пригодится, источник: http://jquery-docs.ru/effects/toggle/

Comment: У вас прблемки с рахитектурой.

Comment: PHP код, чтобы он работал, нужно иначе вставлять в JS код, а то у тебя получается что <?php echo $post[ это продолжение текста... Например можно так var id = <?=$post['id']; ?>

Comment: Позаменял все свои <?php echo $post['id']; ?> на var id = <?=$post['id']; ?> и ничего не вышло. Точнее, контент вообще перестал открываться.

Comment: я понял, вам никто не поможет. вы задали вопрос и выключили думалку. просто сделайте как я сказал в комментарии к ответу и не умничайте. **форму выводите один раз**

Comment: Я и сделал, как вы сказали. Что ж, жалко заменить пару букв - ваше дело.

Comment: мне ничего не жалко - я просто не имею представление что вы делаете, ответ на перемещение формы я дал, нужно что-то еще, делайте новый вопрос, может кто-то и ответит

Comment: "я просто не имею представление что вы делаете"<br>
Я же все расписал - http://codepad.org/OUWareCH что тут непонятного?

Comment: @gm-111 - чтобы перенести строку не надо пользоваться <br> нужно ставить два пробела и потом знак переноса <ENTER>

Comment: Хрен пойми этот хешкод, спасибо, запомню.

Answer (score 1):

Вот исправленная версия вашего скрипта, дело в том, что  toggle там не подходит:

```js
$(function() {
  /* Start DocumentReady */
  var $hidecont = $('div.hideWrap>div.hideCont');
  /* StartClickFunction */
  $('div.hideWrap a.hideBtn').on('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $parent = $this.parent();
    if ($this.hasClass('show')) {
      hide_block($this);
      return false;
    }
    if ($parent !== $hidecont.parent()) {
      hide_block($hidecont.parent().find('.hideBtn'), function() {
        $parent.append($hidecont);
        show_block($this);
      }, 'fast');
    } else show_block($this);
    return false;
  });

  function hide_block($block, callback, speed) {
    speed = speed || 'normal';
    $block.removeClass('show');
    return $hidecont.slideUp(speed, callback);
  }

  function show_block($block, callback, speed) {
    speed = speed || 'normal';
    $block.addClass('show');
    return $hidecont.slideDown(speed, callback);
  }

  /* End DocumentReady */
});
```

```css
.hideWrap {
  text-align: left;
  clear: both;
}

.hideBtn {
  display: block;
  background: transparent url('http://likbezz.ru/_example/_img/_lib1/_plus.gif') no-repeat left center;
  font: bold 11px/15px Verdana, sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  padding: 1px 14px 2px;
}

.hideBtn.show {
  background-image: url('http://likbezz.ru/_example/_img/_lib1/_minus.gif');
}

.hideCont {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js?ver=1.7.2"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://likbezz.ru/_fr/3/1844975.js"></script>
<div id="exContent" style="text-align:left;padding-top:50px;">
  <div class="hideWrap">
    <a class="hideBtn" href="javascript://" title="Показать\Скрыть блок">Показать</a>

    <div class="hideCont">Здесь располагается содержимое class "hideCont"</div>
  </div>
  <br />
  <br />
  <div class="hideWrap">
    <a class="hideBtn" href="javascript://" title="Показать\Скрыть блок">Показать</a>

  </div>
  <br />
  <br />
  <div class="hideWrap">
    <a class="hideBtn" href="javascript://" title="Показать\Скрыть блок">Показать</a>

  </div>
</div>
```

Я убрал оттуда тему с куками, т.к. к вопросу она не относится

Comment: Я хочу использовать скрипт как быстрые ответы на комментарии. На каждом комментарии есть кнопка, нажимаешь на нее и появляется форма.
Я взял ваш исправленный скрипт, поставил. И вот сколько сообщений на странице, столько и форм появляется, когда я нажимаю на кнопку.

Comment: сделайте новый fiddle или ссылку дайте

Comment: дык вы форму одну сделайте, а id сообщения берите из комментария самого, типа data-id (если я правильно понял проблему) [вот так примерно](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/kKs8g/5/)

Comment: Вроде понял, но сделал - ничего не получилось.
http://codepad.org/OUWareCH - вот, все расписал.

Comment: `$hidecont='#postform'` сделайте просто, `#postform` скройте по умолчанию в css, `<div class="hideCont">` уберите из кода (вы правда думаете, что кто-то может прочитать ваши мысли и угадать что вы думаете про то что программа должна делать ? )

Comment: От того, что я скрою форму, она не будет двоиться? Она и так с скрыта.
(Причем тут это?)

Answer (score -1):

Используйте методы insertBefore и appendChild чистого javascript. Данными методами легко можно перемещать определённый контент по странице в мгновение ока. И именно перемещать. Эти ваши библиотеки вовсю пользуются этими методами.

```
parentElem.insertBefore(newElem, target);
parentElem.appendChild(newElem);
```

[Вот тут более подробно](http://javascript.ru/tutorial/dom/modify)

Comment: чистый жаваскрипт вообще не имеет DOM расширения.

Comment: Ну не хочется тыкать вас в контекст вопроса, и, по этому поводу употреблённому значению слова "чистый".

Comment: ну а зачем вы занимаетесь евнгилизмом чистого js, учитывая что за контекстом вопроса может стоять немереное  количество кода с использованием jQuery, и писать с использованием функций DOM в данном случае будет не только не полезно, но и вредно (гомогенность кода, увеличение размера скрипта) то что вы пропагандируется называется псевдооптимизация.

Comment: Вот тут вы совершенно не правы. Предложенные методы одной строчкой заменяют целую библиотечную функцию. Не это ли оптимизация?

Comment: оптимизация это когда мы заменяем там где надо, ато можно на "вопрос странно работает $a*2 в php" ответ - делайте на ассемблере сдвигом.

Comment: Послушайте. Не расстраивайте моё впечатление о вас. Либо у вас ещё не так много опыта. Либо вы говорите как типичный вордпресс-программист, который ничего не умеет кроме как "подключать и настраивать галочками модули для сайта". Не нужно бросаться из крайности в крайность. Ключевое слово в использовании библиотек - это разум. А то получается, что без jquery не могут уже сложить два числа. На читабельности кода JS сказывается иммено передозировка подключаемыми модулями, где из страницы получается сплошная каша-малаша.

Comment: это у вас не так много опыта, кроме того, вы тупо и мстительно заминусовали несколько моих ответов, совершенно без комментария. кто тут говорит об опыте.